# What would be the right datatype to store the body content of an Email in local database?

Tags: postgresql, jsp

I am building a Web application using jsp that reads the mails from the inbox of gmail using javamail api and IMAP. I am also planning on storing the emails in my local database (postgres). In a table names as Qmail, I have 4 columns: from, to, subject and message. What would be the apt datatype for storing the message.

Comment: Use [`text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)

Comment: wondering how you gonna deal with atatchments..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Text only takes in the message content before a new line.
For example if a mail contains:
Testing storage,

Regards,
Siddharth Ganesh

The text field only stores "Testing storage".

Comment: Then you are inserting the data incorrectly. A `text` column can most certainly contain text with newlines. Another possible explanation is, that your SQL client doesn't display multi line strings correctly.

Comment: @jian Will store the attachments in local storage and store the path of the attachments on the db.